# NHibernate 2nd level cache does not invalidate entities map on the same table

Tags: nhibernate, appfabric, second-level-cache

I'm using NHibernate 3.2 with appfabric 1.1 for the 2nd level cache.
I’ve 2 classes mapped on the same table. The first class **AFullEntity** (MonitorLayoutData in the sample), inherit a second class which is lightweight class (MonitorLayout). MonitorLayoutData contains a heavy property that is not present in the base class. For example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Entities.MonitorLayout,Entities" table="MonitorLayouts2" lazy="false" schema="dbo" polymorphism="explicit">
    <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
    <id name="Id" column="MonitorLayout_ID" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="MonitorLayout" type="string" />
    <property name="UserId" column="User_ID" type="int" />
    <property name="IsPublic" column="IsPublic" type="Boolean" not-null="true" />
    <property name="ViewGuid" column="ViewGuid" type="string" not-null="true" />
    <property name="TreeNode" column="TreeNode" type="string" />
    <property name="IncludeNodeChildren" column="IncludeNodeChildren" type="Boolean" />

  </class>

  <class name="Entities.MonitorLayoutData,Entities" table="MonitorLayouts2" lazy="false" schema="dbo" polymorphism="explicit">
    <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
    <id name="Id" column="MonitorLayout_ID" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="MonitorLayout" type="string" />
    <property name="UserId" column="User_ID" type="int" />
    <property name="IsPublic" column="IsPublic" type="Boolean" not-null="true" />
    <property name="ViewGuid" column="ViewGuid" type="string" not-null="true" />
    <property name="TreeNode" column="TreeNode" type="string" />
    <property name="IncludeNodeChildren" column="IncludeNodeChildren" type="Boolean" />
    <property name="LayoutData" column="LayoutData" type="BinaryBlob" not-null="false"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Those classes use an explicit polymorphism to retrieve only entities for the selected type like note in the documentation : “Explicit polymorphism is useful when two different classes are mapped to the same table (this allows a "lightweight" class that contains a subset of the table columns)”.

However I got a problem when entities are cached. When I update a AFullEntity changes are not report in the lightweight class and this is a big problem for us.
I try other mechanism like subclass or extends but NHibernate force me to declare a discriminator element, which is not required for me.

**Is there a way to do this ?**

Comment: Did you look at [Lazy Property](http://ayende.com/blog/4377/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties) instead of sub-classing it?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are two separate objects, each with their own identity in the cache. Possible workaround would be to disable caching for lightweight objects or evict the lightweight object from the cache when the heavy object is loaded. Loading the heavy and light objects in the same session seems to me to defeat the purpose.

Comment: I already know that there are 2 separates objects, I'm looking for a mecanisme to invalidate "linked" entities. First would like to use the subclass mecanism, but seems not possible to use it without discriminator. Second I found the ILifecycle interface, which could resolve the problem. But this is an ugly solution. EntityInterceptor may be the third solution.